# More efficient na.aggregate for grouped by maximum in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, rcpp, zoo

I have a data frame that is roughly 20,000 x 300 in size that I am currently using `na.aggregate` from the `zoo` package to fill in the maximum by group for every column. If there is all NA's in the group it should return `NA`.  I am trying to find a more efficient solution for this chunk of my code to speed it up.  Here is a toy data frame as well as an attempt at a `dplyr` solution that was about ~10x slower than the `na.aggregate` version:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

# toy data frame
DF <- tibble(group=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",2),rep("C",3)),
             Col1=rep(NA_real_,9),
             Col2=c(5,3,2,NA,NA,NA,1,2,NA),
             Col3=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,2,3,NA))

# na.aggregate solution
na.agg <- function(DF){

  agg.max <- suppressWarnings(na.aggregate(DF,DF$group,FUN=max))
  agg.max[,2:ncol(agg.max)] <- apply(agg.max[,2:ncol(agg.max)],2,as.numeric)

  return(agg.max)
}

# dplyr solution
dplyr.agg <- function(DF){

  Sol.2 <- DF %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate_all(funs(case_when(
      all(is.na(.))~NA_real_,
      is.na(.)~max(.,na.rm=TRUE),
      TRUE ~ as.numeric(I(.))))) 
}

# Timing test
res <- microbenchmark(na.agg(DF),dplyr.agg(DF))

print(res)

Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    na.agg(DF)  1.698281  1.879652  2.122334  2.063809  2.297201  3.763934   100
 dplyr.agg(DF) 10.730040 11.553523 12.484254 12.068044 12.778734 21.239836   100
```

Is there an `rcpp`, `data.table` or better `dplyr` solution that is quicker??

Comment: A speed benchmark with a **9**-row data.frame is completely useless

Comment: @docendodiscimus speed improvements were very similar over the big dataset.

Comment: I very much doubt that. My own benchmarking with a 1e5 row data set has shown that at that point the dplyr approach is already noticeably faster than your na.agg solution. And of course there are data.table solutions that scales even better (~1/3 of dplyr in my scenario)

Comment: @docendodiscimus super helpful

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty more speed to be eeked out of `na.agg` yet. Don't do `na.aggregate` over the entire `DF`, as the inclusion of the `group` column means everything gets converted to a character, which will slow things down. Run it on `DF[-1]` excluding `group` and you don't even need the as.numeric conversion post-hoc.

```
na.agg2 <- function(DF) {
  DF[-1] <- na.aggregate(DF[-1], DF$group, FUN=function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else max(x) )
  DF
}
```

This markedly reduces the execution speed compared to your current `na.agg`:

```
microbenchmark(na.agg(DF),na.agg2(DF))
#Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#  na.agg(DF) 2.127476 2.145621 2.232542 2.163216 2.216366  3.433873   100
# na.agg2(DF) 1.047977 1.055675 1.560371 1.062455 1.080783 49.378785   100
```

Using `data.table` seems to be speedier again:

```
DT <- copy(DF)
DT <- as.data.table(DT)
DT[,
  lapply(.SD, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA_real_ else
                             replace(x,is.na(x),max(x,na.rm=TRUE))), 
  by=group
]
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip I will definitely do that.  Would be curious to know if there was an elegant rcpp or other solution that gained a lot of efficiency over na.aggregate.

Comment: @SteveGermani - added another `data.table` solution that is faster again.